# How to make the jQuery datePicker popup opaque and always in the foreground?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I am working on a website for a Wildlife Resort Near Bangalore http://www.innthewild.com and have been trying to solve a simple problem on jQuery for hours.

I've researched all over Google as well as StackOverflow, but since my problem is a bit unique, I havent been able to find a solution.

Essentially, I have a jimage-slider widget and a datepicker widget both from jQuery as part of my home page design. Now the issue is when I do click on the input box to activate datePicker, the datePicker popup that comes out, keeps getting pushed to the background by the caption updates from the jimage-slider widget.

Further this issue seems browser specific, since IE10, the datePicker is in the foreground, where as in Chrome the datePicker keeps getting pushed to the background. So on IE10 the page looks fine, the caption updates are in the background, and I can easily pick a date. Whereas in Chrome things get messed up. I am guessing its got something to do with how the browsers implement their rendering algorithms - but am looking for some CSS property changes that I could make, either on jimage-slider OR on datePicker to get the behavior I need. Essentially either making sure datePicker is always in the foreground, OR jimage-slider is always in the background...

For source code details, kindly visit the above link and view source via the browser...

Thanks very much for any pointers, this is my first time playing iwth jQuery, so am not fully aware of how to go about things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your CSS:

`#sliderFrame { z-index: -50 }`

Tested on Chrome.

The jquery UI datapicker is given a z-index of 1 in inline CSS, so we're choosing a z-index that is less than this to ensure it appears beneath it in the stacking order.

Comment: Super! I knew there would be a property to control it, but didn't know which one. I was trying to play with display, etc. Thanks very much Toby!